# scipy.stats.multivariable_norm.pdf: "The input matrix must be symmetric positive semidefinite."

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, scipy.stats

So I have the following code below.

```py
L = np.array([1,2,3])
M = np.array([1,2,3])
Q = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=(3,3))
S = Q.T*Q
print(sp.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(L,M,S))
```

Clearly `S` is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. I can prove it using linear algebra theory. However, scipy complains that it isn't when running the above code. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you use the `*` operator as a matrix multiplication? It is element wise multiplication.

Comment: Normally, when I use the `*` operator it gets interpreted by python as matrix multiplication.

Comment: It won't (unless you are using the class `matrix`, but it is not recommended now). Use `@` operator for matrix multiplication. For conventional numpy arrays, the `*` operator always performs element wise multiplication.

Comment: I see. I guess when the matrices are the same dimensions it gets interpreted as elementwise multiplication. Thanks!

Comment: *"I guess when the matrices are the same dimensions ..."*  It is not the number of dimensions that determines this.  It is the *type of object* that you are working with.  NumPy has the `ndarray` object (which is what `np.array(...)` creates), for which `*` is elementwise multiplication, and the `matrix` object, for which `*` is matrix multiplication.  Note that the `matrix` object is undergoing a (slow but steady) deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

Like the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983044/scipy-stats-multivariable-norm-pdf-the-input-matrix-must-be-symmetric-positive#comment130629779_73983044) by Mechanic Pig says, replace `*` (element-wise multiplication on Numpy arrays) with `@`.

```py
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

L = np.array([1, 2, 3])
M = np.array([1, 2, 3])
Q = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(3, 3))
S = Q.T @ Q
print(sp.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(L, M, S))
```

prints, in my case, `0.0003568248543110567`.

You can verify your "covariance" is positive-definite by just comparing

- `np.linalg.eig(Q.T * Q)[0]`, using element-wise multiply (will likely have negative values), vs
- `np.linalg.eig(Q.T @ Q)[0]` (will have no negative values).